# Errorlevel not working when using date command in batch file

Tags: date, batch-file

I've made this code to change the date. But when i enter a wrong date, the `errorlevel` command appears beeing ignored.

```
@echo off
@setlocal enableextensions
@cd /d "%~dp0"
mode 48,12

:start
cls
echo.
echo 1 - Mudar data
echo 2 - Retornar a data atual
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
choice /n /c:12 /m "Digite uma op‡Æo:"%1
if errorlevel ==2 goto 2
if errorlevel ==1 goto 1

:1
cls
set /p "dd=Digite o dia: "
cls
set /p "mm=Digite o mes: %dd% - "
cls
set /p "aa=Digite o ano: %dd% - %mm% - "
cls
date %dd%-%mm%-%aa%
if not errorlevel 1 (
cls
echo Data modificada.
pause
goto start
)

if errorlevel 1 (
cls
echo Erro ao mudar a data.
pause
goto start
)

:2
cls
w32tm /resync >nul 2>nul
cls
goto start
```

I supposed that if the date was typed wrong, it would appears a `echo Erro ao mudar a data.` But it only opens the `date` command screen asking to change the date because was typed wrong.

---

**Edit 1**

Just update my code including the commands to stop the `Windows Time Service`, because even i changed the date, after sometime the real date was replaced again.

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions
cd /d "%~dp0"
mode 42,12

:begin
cls
echo ------------------------------------------
echo          MUDAR A DATA DO WINDOWS
echo ------------------------------------------
echo( &echo(
echo  1 - Escolher a data & echo( &echo  2 - Retornar para a data atual
echo( & echo( &echo(
choice /n /c:12 /m "Digite uma op‡Æo:"%1
goto :lab%errorlevel%

:lab1
cls & set /p "dd=Digite o dia: "
cls & set /p "mm=Digite o mes: %dd% / "
cls & set /p "aa=Digite o ano: %dd% / %mm% / "

date %dd%/%mm%/%aa% <nul && (

    cls
    net stop w32time >nul 2>nul
    sc config w32time start= disabled >nul 2>nul
    echo Data modificada.
    timeout /nobreak /t 2 >nul 2>nul
    goto begin
) || (
      cls & echo Erro ao mudar a data.
      echo( &echo( &echo(
      pause
      goto begin
)

:lab2
net start w32time >nul 2>nul
sc config w32time start= demand >nul
cls & w32tm /resync >nul 2>&1
echo Data atual retornada.
timeout /nobreak /t 2 >nul 2>nul
cls & goto begin
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you redirect input to nul for the DATE command, you still get the error message and prompt to enter a valid date, but then the command immediately fails with an appropriate error return code.

I find it much easier to use `&&` and `||` to handle success and failure instead of using IF.

```
date %dd%-%mm%-%aa% <nul && (
  cls
  echo Data modificada.
) || (
  cls
  echo Erro ao mudar a data.
)
pause
goto start
```

Comment: Nice!! it worked fine and clear! i realized that `>nul` and `<nul` is different. Can you explain me that? I just knowed the `>nul` or `>nul 2>nul`

Comment: @I'mNotHere `>nul` is redirecting output to nul, where `<nul` it is redirecting input from nul

Comment: @I'mNotHere - `<` redirects input, while `>` redirects output. Without a number, `<` redirects stdin, which is the same as `0<`. And `>` redirects stdout, which is the same as `1>`

Comment: Just one last point! I didn't found if is possibile limit the characteres that will be used. For example writing the `dd` im free to write anything. But i wanted only allowing numbers and 2 characteres. is it possibile? for only wirite for example `05` (day 5)

Comment: @I'mNotHere - That is an entirely different question. If you scour the internet you can find different strategies for achieving this with batch, though there is no trivial, built in solution. But I have to agree with Mofi's comment - you can ditch your prompts and just issue `DATE` without any argument and it will ask for a new date, including a prompt specifying the correct format.

Comment: @I'mNotHere Not difficult at all, you can test for it `set /p "mm=Digite o mes: %dd% - "` then `set test=%mm:~2,1%` finally `if defined test echo you entered more than 2 digits`

Comment: Thank you! The `<` made the difference!

Answer (score 2):

Rename your lables `:1` and `:2` with `:lab1` and `:lab` 2 then remove these lines:

```
if errorlevel ==2 goto 2
if errorlevel ==1 goto 1
```

and replace them with this line:

```
goto :lab%errorlevel%
```

You should then only have:

```
choice /n /c:12 /m "Digite uma op‡Æo:"%1
goto :lab%errorlevel%
```

Then other observations, remove the `echo.` lines and replace them with `echo(`
`cls` lines on their own looks ugly, so I like to integrate them by running them with `&` with other commands to make it look nicer
So a total cleanup will be:

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions
cd /d "%~dp0"
mode 48,12

:begin
cls
echo( & echo 1 - Mudar data & echo 2 - Retornar a data atual
echo( & echo( &echo( &echo(
choice /n /c:12 /m "Digite uma op‡Æo:"%1
goto :lab%errorlevel%

:lab1
cls & set /p "dd=Digite o dia: "
cls & set /p "mm=Digite o mes: %dd% - "
cls & set /p "aa=Digite o ano: %dd% - %mm% - "
cls & echo %dd%-%mm%-%aa% | date
if not errorlevel 1 (
    cls
    echo Data modificada.
    pause
    goto begin
  ) else (
      cls & echo Erro ao mudar a data.
      pause
      goto start
)

:lab2
cls & w32tm /resync >nul 2>&1
cls & goto begin
```

Comment: I made a change to the answer to eliminate the after effect of a wrong date entered which will wait for prompt and it works with errorlevel `echo %dd%-%mm%-%aa% | date`